# Cassandra CQL Mapping in F#

Tags: f#, cassandra

I am having a problem trying to map a property on my type to a mapping in Cassandra.

I have it working in C#, but i am struggling with the F#

The error i get is: Stack Trace: [System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Expression x => new Tuple`2(x.Id, ToFSharpFunc(x => x.WithName("player_id"))) is not a property or field. Parameter name: expression]

on Line 26, if I removed "fun(x:ColumnMap)->x.WithName("player_id")" it compiles but then it will not map to the correct table column. My models property name is "Id" but i need it to map to "player_id"

```
open Cassandra
open Cassandra.Mapping
open System

type Ranking = 
{ Id : Guid
  Alias : string
  Kills : int
  Deaths : int }

type Player = {Id: Guid; Alias: string; Dob: DateTime; FullName: string}

type CassyMappings() = 
inherit Cassandra.Mapping.Mappings()
do 
    base.For<Player>()
            .TableName("players")
            .PartitionKey("player_id")
            .Column(fun(x:Player)-> x.Id) 
            .Column(fun(x:Player)-> x.Alias)
            .Column(fun(x:Player)-> x.FullName)
            .Column(fun(x:Player)-> x.Dob) |> ignore
    base.For<Ranking>()
        .TableName("rankings")
        .PartitionKey("player_id")
        .Column(fun (x : Ranking) -> x.Id, fun(x:ColumnMap)->x.WithName("player_id")) 
        .Column(fun (x : Ranking) -> x.Alias)
        .Column(fun (x : Ranking) -> x.Kills)
        .Column(fun (x : Ranking) -> x.Deaths) |> ignore

MappingConfiguration.Global.Define<CassyMappings>()

printfn "Works fine!"
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8IiYhg

here is a link to the C# http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/csharp-driver-cassandra-new-mapper-linq-improvements

Comment: Put your code in the actual question.  Also, please explain what "struggling with the F# means" - include any error messages etc.

Comment: sure, no problem.. I created a DotNetFiddle for it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8IiYhg) 

my error is "Stack Trace:

[System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Expression x => new Tuple`2(x.Id, ToFSharpFunc(x => x.WithName("player_id"))) is not a property or field.
Parameter name: expression]"

Comment: on Line 26, if I removed "fun(x:ColumnMap)->x.WithName("player_id")" it compiles but then it will not map to the correct table column.  My models property name is "Id" but i need it to map to "player_id"

Comment: Put all of this including the actual code, not a link in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing parentheses.

The expression on line 26 is getting compiled as:

```
.Column(fun (x : Ranking) -> (x.Id, fun(x:ColumnMap)->x.WithName("player_id")) )
```

That is, as an expression that takes a `Ranking` as parameter and produces a tuple of `int` and a function as result. Just to be more clear, here's a more expanded version of the same code:

```
.Column(
   fun (x : Ranking) -> 
      let id = x.Id
      let f = fun (x:ColumnMap)->x.WithName("player_id")
      id, f )
```

The result of such expression is a `Tuple<_,_>`, and CQL interpreter expects a plain property access instead, and this is exactly what it tells you in the error message.

But what you really (apparently) intended to do was to call a different overload of `.Column`, which takes two parameters, one expression and one function. To prevent the compiler from considering the second function a part of the previous function's body, you just need to add parentheses around both functions:

```
.Column(
   (fun (x : Ranking) -> x.Id),
   (fun (x:ColumnMap)->x.WithName("player_id")) )
```

Or to put it on one line:

```
.Column( (fun (x : Ranking) -> x.Id), (fun (x:ColumnMap)->x.WithName("player_id")) )
```